# DB file size from master..sysaltfiles

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve db sizes of all databases in my SQL Server 2005 instance. I found this

```
select filename, size, 8192.0E * size / 1048576.0E as result
from master..sysaltfiles
```

Is the result varibale in KB? How can get this to MB? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result must be in MB. I tried your query and have result size in MB.

Answer (score 0):

result varibale in MB.